# The output of "python --version" and "python3 --version" are not the same

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda

I'm trying to make my Python and Python 3 versions match. When I do the command `python --version`, I get 3.8.9, but when I run the command `python3 --version`, I get an updated version 3.11.3.

Ultimately, I'm trying to use a [Conda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conda_(package_manager)) environment with Python version 3.10, which I created by doing `conda create -n env_name python=3.10` and I'm seeing that the Python version is 3.8.9 and the python3 version is indeed 3.10. How can I get the versions to match? It's an issue within the Conda environment and outside of it, as I demonstrated above.

I've tried updating my Python version, but that won't work. If it helps, when I run `which python` I get the output `python: aliased to /usr/bin/python3`.

Comment: Try `which python3` and see if it's different from `which python`.

Comment: Ah, yes. When I run which python 3 I get '/Users/rileypittman/miniconda3/envs/ersilia/bin/python3'. Does this help?

Comment: Ok, so you have two different installs.  You're picking up one through your path, and the other is the result of an alias.  So you have a complete explanation.  You should be able to do whatever you want.